# Is it possible to get the name of a partially applied function?

Tags: scala, partial-application

Suppose I have defined a function:

```
def hello(name:String, words:String) = println("Hello!" + name + words)
```

Then I defined a partial function:

```
def p = hello _
```

Print p, displayed:

```
(String, String) => Unit = <function2>
```

There's no function name displayed. Is it possible to get the original method name `hello` from the partial function `p`?

Comment: Edited "partial function" to "partially applied function" in the tag and question title, so that the appropriate people will be attracted to (or repelled from) this question.

Comment: To add to Rex's comment, a "partial function" is a function that is not defined for all input in its domain type.  The cannonical partial function is something like def f(x : Int) = 1/x.  Scala also has a PartialFunction trait that function objects may implement if they want to answer a query indicating where they are and are not defined.  Neither concept should be confused with partial application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *has* been some discussion on the mailing lists recently about a language construct that allows you to identify the current **method** that you're in.  It would be called something like `thisMethod` and would essentially do for methods what `this` does for class instances.

I'd be interested to see how this interacts with functions (which are a different concept from methods). Your `p` is an anonymous function created from partially applying the `hello` method (again, you need to be careful here, a "partially *applied* function is a very different thing from a `PartialFunction`).  The actual method then invoked would be `apply` on this function object, and there are several possibilities as to how `thisMethod` could behave in such a case.

Whatever happens, `p` is just an object reference, don't expect to **ever** be able to access it as a name.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Its a feature I'd love to have, but it has serious conceptual problems like, what should happen, when the same function is given two names ... it should still be the same function, shouldn't it?

update in response to comment:

def p = hello _
   def q = p

What is the name of q? p? or hello? or println? I have a hard time imagining a solution that is simple, consistent and usefull.

Comment: thanks! But I don't understand how the function is given two names? I hope there is a method say `getOriMethodName` that returns `hello`, will this cause some problems? Sorry I'm a newbie to scala.

Comment: Formally speaking, we don't write functions we write procedures that compute functions.  def f(x : Int) = 2 * x and def g(x : Int) = x + x are two different procedures that compute the same function.  But that's just pedantry and I think this answer should not be voted up because it's besides the point of what's being asked for - a debugging tool.

Answer (score 2):

... that is actually a "partially applied function" that is created anonymously by calling your hello function without the parameters being applied.  It does not have an explicit name to show.